# How to call a function only one time per week or month?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nstimer

I am asking myself how to call a function only one time per week or month?
I thought about NSTimer, but that only works during the app is active, doesn't it?
So maybe I have to save the current time and determine the past days every time I start the app.
Or is there a simpler method, like a simple function call? ;-)

Help appreciated

Comment: You may have to do a mix of both there. The app may stay alive for months together in worst(best) case.

Comment: I think you need to add a little more context to your question, such as what running the function will achieve and how critical to the app it is that the function *does* actually run once a week or month. I can however state at this point that `NSTimer` is not the way to go.

Comment: @praveen-s If it is critical that this function run at designated intervals then relying on the end user to keep the app running in the background and not *hard* quit it is certainly not the best way of achieving this.

Comment: The function is only to fetch an xml from a server, and look if there is some data newer than the data on phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to store your last synced date in database/user defaults, and then need to fetch from database/user defaults

and need to pass both date, synced date and current date to following function

```
-(int)howManyDaysHavePast:(NSDate*)lastDate today:(NSDate*)today {
NSDate *startDate = lastDate;
NSDate *endDate = today;

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
int days = [components day];
return days;
}
```

and then you need to check how many days have passed

```
if([self howManyDaysHavePast:lastSyncedDate today:[NSDate date]]>=7)
{
   [self callFunction];
}
```